# How to take only Latitude and Longitude values from CLLocation instead of taking full location details in swift

Tags: ios, swift, latitude-longitude, cllocation, location-services

I am trying to take latitude and longitude values from cllocation. Its coming full location data. Since I need only latitude and longitude data to send my back end. I have to send multiple latitude and longitude data to server.

Even I tried with CLLocationCoordinate2D, but, its taking CLLocationCoordinate inside the data while sending to server.

> I want to take in single array both latitude and longitude, not in two
>   arrays.
>
> Can anyone suggest me, how to take only latitude and longitude values
>   to append to array in swift?

Here is my code

```
    var myLocations: [CLLocation] = []

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        myLocations.append(locations[0] as CLLocation)


}
```

> ```
> output is
> ```

```
<+10.92088132,+77.56955708> +/- 1414.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 22/03/18, 1:17:30 PM India Standard Time

[<+10.92088132,+77.56955708> +/- 1414.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 22/03/18, 1:17:30 PM India Standard Time]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
let loc = myLocations.last

let lat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude

let lon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
```

then declare arr like this

```
    var myLocations: [String] = []

    let last = locations[0] as CLLocation

    myLocations.append("\(last.coordinate.latitude),\(last.coordinate.longitude)")
```

Comment: I want to take in single array both latitude and longitude, not in two arrays.

Comment: If I take CLLocationCoordinate2D, in array CLLocationCoordinate2D also showing, but, I want only latitude and longitude values.

Comment: every single object use obj.latitude and objc.longitude to get the value

Comment: I have to send only latitude and longitude values, thats it, I don't want to send any other strings in side that array.

Comment: [__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 10.920881319999994, longitude: 77.569557079999967)] its coming like this, i want to remove __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D from this data

Comment: @Sh_Khan [CLLocationCoordinate2D](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationcoordinate2d) only has two properties - latitude and longitude.

Comment: @Sh_Khan then don't print the whole thing, print just the actual coordintates `print("\(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")`

Comment: CLLocation has full address of location data.

Comment: Its working after you edited. Accepted your answer and up voted.

Comment: @JeremyP yes converted to array of strings

Answer (score 1):

```
    var  location = CLLocation()
    location = myLocations.last! as CLLocation   
    let lat = location.coordinate.latitude
    let longit = location.coordinate.longitude
```

Comment: Here, how you adding to mylocations variable?

Comment: You can append only Latitude & longitude & can send to server as per your requirement

Comment: I don't want to add two seperate

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper .. Yes in only one array you can append

Comment: I need it like [{latitude : value, longitude :  value}, {latitude : value, longitude :  value}] like this format